# How to add ip address to a whitelist wfa rule in azure using azure cli?

Tags: azure, web-application-firewall, azure-cli

I tried adding like below but getting error with syntax as below.

```
az network application-gateway waf-policy custom-rule update
--resource-group rp-licaltcs-aks-prod --policy-name waf-licaltcs-prod-eastus --name WhitelistIP --set matchConditions[0].matchValues="20.80.71.229/24" "20.80.71.228/24"
```

> Expect <class 'list'>, got 20.80.71.229/24 (<class 'str'>)

Similarly.

```
az network application-gateway waf-policy custom-rule update --resource-group rp-licaltcs-aks-prod --policy-name waf-licaltcs-prod-eastus --name WhitelistIP --set matchConditions[0].matchValues="20.80.71.229,20.80.71.228"
```

> Expect <class 'list'>, got 20.80.71.229,20.80.71.228 (<class 'str'>)

This one working.

```
az network application-gateway waf-policy custom-rule update \
  --resource-group rp-licaltcs-aks-prod \
  --policy-name waf-licaltcs-prod-eastus \
  --name WhitelistIP \
  --set "matchConditions[0].matchValues=['20.80.71.229', '20.80.71.228']"
```

But one more issue now, existing values are replaced instead of appending it.

So I thought fetching previous values first and pass that also.

When I run below command.

```
az network application-gateway waf-policy custom-rule show --resource-group rp-licaltcs-aks-prod --policy-name waf-licaltcs-prod-eastus --name WhitelistIP --query matchConditions[0].matchValues --output tsv
```

will provide ouput as below

```
20.80.71.229
20.80.71.228
```

But if I assign that to a variable, it is picking only the first value.

```
existing_ips=$(az network application-gateway waf-policy custom-rule show --resource-group rp-licaltcs-aks-prod --policy-name waf-licaltcs-
prod-eastus --name WhitelistIP --query matchConditions[0].matchValues --output json | ./jq.exe -r '.[]')
```

EIther with json or tsv, it is assinging only the first value of ip.

total script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# The IP address you want to add
new_ip="20.80.71.230"

# Get the current list of whitelisted IP addresses
existing_ips=$(az network application-gateway waf-policy custom-rule show --resource-group rp-licaltcs-aks-prod --policy-name waf-licaltcs-prod-eastus --name WhitelistIP --query matchConditions[0].matchValues --output tsv)

# Check if the new IP is already in the list
if echo "$existing_ips" | grep -q "$new_ip"; then
  echo "The IP address $new_ip is already in the whitelist."
else
  # If not, add it to the list
  updated_ips=$(echo -e "$existing_ips\n$new_ip" | tr '\n' ',' | sed 's/,$//')
  az network application-gateway waf-policy custom-rule update \
    --resource-group rp-licaltcs-aks-prod \
    --policy-name waf-licaltcs-prod-eastus \
    --name WhitelistIP \
    --set "matchConditions[0].matchValues=[$updated_ips]"
  echo "The IP address $new_ip has been added to the whitelist."
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

A powershell list consists of elements separated by a comma.

`"foo","bar"` is a list consisting of the strings `"foo"` and `"bar"`. `"foo, bar"` is a string with the content `"foo, bar"`.

Thus you should use `matchConditions[0].matchValues="20.80.71.229","20.80.71.228"`.

Comment: working if I pass like this matchValues=['20.80.71.229', '20.80.71.228']